# Shared events text on search results

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

We have a multisite solution .
It looks like

```
Sitecore
- Contenent
   -Country one 
   -Country Two
     ....
   -Contry X
```

We have shared events for country sites:

```
    /Global/Events/Event One
   /Global/Events/Events Two
   ....
   /Global/Events/Events X
```

These events are displayed on Country Site .
My problem is when we search on country site text displayed on events doesn't appear on search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your scope I suggest you to use Computed index field.

You can read on next [link](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2013/03/Sitecore-7-Computed-Index-Fields.aspx) about Computed Index Field.

Just follow steps from link and you get needed result.

Answer (score 0):

did you make sure the root of the shared content (/Global/Events/) is included in the index root?

You can verify the items in the index using Luke.

Also make sure the search is not performed based on the current item as the start/root of the search (because that's different from the root of the shared content).

Comment: Yes, your ideea is good, but I need computed index field, because we have a lot of rules.

Comment: Computed index field are visible (when Stored), so that should help...Did it?

Comment: Yes, I can see index fields with Luke.